# Showing a loading message until the blob file is downloaded

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am printing a bill as a pdf document after submitting the billing form. The service that is downloading the blob file is as follows.

```
export default [createLogic({
  type: reportTypes.REPORT,
  latest: true,
  debounce: 2000,

  process({ MockHTTPClient, getState, action }, dispatch, done) {


    dispatch(reportActions.queryStart())
    let HTTPClient;
    if (MockHTTPClient) {
      HTTPClient = MockHTTPClient;
    } else {
      HTTPClient = API;
    }

    HTTPClient.Post(endPoints.REPORTS_BILL, action.payload.reportOptions)
      .then(
        (resp) => {
          return resp.data
        })
      .then((data) => {
        dispatch(reportActions.getReportSuccess(data));

        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = `data:application/octet-stream;base64,${data}`;
        var today = new Date();
        var date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
        var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds() + ":" + today.getMilliseconds();
        var dateTime = date + ' ' + time;
        var fileName = dateTime + "billing.pdf";
        link.download = fileName;
        link.click();

        var base64str = data;
        var binary = atob(base64str.replace(/\s/g, ''));
        var len = binary.length;
        var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(len);
        var view = new Uint8Array(buffer);
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          view[i] = binary.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        var blob = new Blob([view], { type: "application/pdf" });
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        window.open(url);
        dispatch(reportActions.getReportSuccess(data))

      })
      .then(() => dispatch(reportActions.queryEnd()))
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch(reportActions.getReportFailed());
        var errorMessage = "Failed to get prductivity data.";
        if (err && err.code == "ECONNABORTED") {
          errorMessage = "Please check your internet connection.";
        }


        dispatch(
          reportActions.getReportFailed({
            title: "Error!",
            message: errorMessage
          })
        );
      })
      .then(() => done()); 
  }
})
]
```

In the Billing Component following is the method that I am calling the service.

```
printBill = () => {
    debugger;
    var reportType = 1;
    var reportFiltersSet = {};
    if (this.billingOptions.length > 0) {
      this.billingOptions.map(v => {
        reportFiltersSet[v.name] = v.value;
      });
    }

    this.props.reportActions.queryStart();
    var reportType = 1; //Thiis need to be dynamic. use this => //this.state.reportType
    var reportFilters = this.state.billingOptions;

    if (
      reportFiltersSet.organization == undefined ||
      reportFiltersSet.department == undefined ||
      reportFiltersSet.division == undefined ||
      reportFiltersSet.billYear == undefined ||
      reportFiltersSet.billMonth == undefined
    ) {
      this.setState({
        reportContentNull: true,
        warning: "Error!",
        errorMessage:
          "Either department or division reqiured with organization , year and month",
        negative: true,
        hidden: false
      });




    this.props.reportActions.getReport({ reportOptions: reportFiltersSet });
    var reportDownloadType = this.state.reportType;
  };
```

I can download the blob file , when I submit the form without any problem. But in user's perspective it is important to show that the loading state in order to have a better user experince. Therefore can anyone help me out to show a loading message during the submit and loading the blob file?

Comment: try to add a state wich name is loading set to true on your reducer when the action getReportSuccess raise, after that on other cases set that to false (like queryEnd) then catch your state change and by changing the state the loading do your proper action in your view

Answer (score 0):

So the Idea is to start loading as soon as `HTTP` calls happens and remove it when response is recieved.

Simple way would be add a loading variable in state and in render check that variable and show spinner.

```
onClick = () => {
  this.setState({ loading: true }, () => {
    Axios.get('/sampelCall')
      .then(result => this.setState({
        loading: false,
        data: [...result.data],
      }));
  });
}


render() {
      const { data, loading } = this.state;
      return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.onClick}>
            Load Data
          </button>
          {loading ? <LoadingSpinner /> : <ResultsTable results={data} />}  // if loading in true will show Spinner
        </div>
      );
}
```

**Note:**

You need to handle loading variable in all cases (Success/Error) else Spinner will keep on loading.